# Using Karate or Postman

Tags: postman, karate

I am new to Karate and I am wondering which is a better tool  for api testing, postman or karate ? Both tools are easy to use but I wonder in long term which is a better tool in terms of automation testing. My aim is to automate the api tests and run them through CI/CD pipeline jobs.
Anyone who has moved to karate from postman, could you please share your experiences on how easy was the migration, what method have you used to migrate postman collections, what benefits have you observed so far by choosing karate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: author of karate here, top 4 reasons: a) parallel execution in CI with aggregated reports b) perf-testing c) websockets d) integrate java code or ui tests - there's a lot more, but I don't want to start a flame war ;)

Comment: Not sure why it's always a `this vs that` question - What works well for you in your context and ticks all the boxes for the things that you need to be productive. Use that one. :) This is more of an opinion based question and is totally going to get closed eventually :D

Answer (score 5):

We evaluated Postman, Karate, and a few other frameworks about three years ago when Karate was still in it's infancy.  Postman did have a lot of pull just because our dev team had a very solid collection that was well maintained, but we quickly realized Postman was not scalable, and simply did not have the features necessary for an automation framework.

We will be starting api testing at my current job sometime this year, and Karate is again the most likely candidate, though we will also consider Postman and Cypress, the later mostly because we are using it for front-end.  But Karate is so easy to use out-of-the-box, has BY FAR the best documentation, and real-time support of any open source framework I've used, and has outstanding integration for DB connections, GraphQl calls, Java interop, and javascript-like syntax.

I love Postman for quick exploratory testing, but for test framework and CI, I don't see how they can compete.

Answer (score 4):

Started testing APIs with Postman and looked for a tool that was better for developers to share their "API knowledge" via GIT.

Came across Karate three years ago and I use it for almost every API call have to make.

Postman is a tool for non developers and for people afraid writing any kind of code.